# Show a paginated ListView and an UpdateView on the same template page

Tags: django, pagination, django-class-based-views

I am trying to create a `Django` page where something can be updated and something can be viewed in a paginated table. The model looks like this:

```
class CostGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse(
            'costgroup_detail', 
            kwargs={
                'costgroup_pk': self.pk,
            }
        )


class Cost(models.Model):
    cost_group = models.ForeignKey(CostGroup)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=50, decimal_places=2)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse(
            'cost_detail', 
            kwargs={
                'cost_pk': self.pk,
            }
        )
```

So the edit form is for the `name` and `description` fields of the `CostGroup` model and the table should show a list of the 'amounts`

I previously had it working by just having an `UpdateView` for the form and the table included in the form template. Now though, as I want to include pagination on the table, I need to use two views on the same page. The page I have designed should look something like this in the end:

[image: Wireframe for Django page]

I am not worried about the styling at the moment my main focus at the moment is getting the form and the table on the same page. In its current state the only thing that I don't have is the pagination for the table:

The view currently looks like this:

```
class CostDetail(UpdateView):
    model = models.Cost
    pk_url_kwarg = 'cost_pk'
    template_name = 'main/cost_detail.html'
    form_class = forms.CostDetailEditForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('cost_list')
```

I have a feeling that leveraging the underlying mixins that the Django CBVs use is probably the way to go but I am not sure how to begin with this.

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This clarification seemed to work better as a new answer)

It looks like you're dealing with both of the tables.  The object level is using CostGroup, while the List view is showing the child records from Cost linked to a CostGroup.  Assuming that is true, here's how I would proceed:

```
class CostDetail(ModelFormMixin, ListView):

    model = CostGroup   # Using the model of the record to be updated
    form_class = YourFormName  # If this isn't declared, get_form_class() will
                               # generate a model form 


    ordering =  ['id']
    paginate_by = 10
    template_name = 'main/cost_detail.html' # Must be declared

    def get_queryset(self):
        # Set the queryset to use the Cost objects that match the selected CostGroup
        self.queryset = Cost.objects.filter(cost_group = get_object())
        # Use super to add the ordering needed for pagination
        return super(CostDetail,self).get_queryset()

    # We want to override get_object to avoid using the redefined get_queryset above
    def get_object(self,queryset=None):  
        queryset = CostGroup.objects.all()
        return super(CostDetail,self).get_object(queryset))

    # Include the setting of self.object in get()
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        # from BaseUpdateView
        self.object = self.get_object()

        return super(CostDetail,self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    # Include the contexts from both
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        context = ModelFormMixin.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context = ListView.get_context_data(**context)
        return context

    # This is the post method found in the Update View
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        # From BaseUpdateView
        self.object = self.get_object()

        # From ProcessFormView
        form = self.get_form()
        self.form = form
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def put(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.post(*args, **kwargs)
```

I haven't tried to run this, so there may be errors. Good luck!

(Remember ccbv.co.uk is your friend when digging into Class-based Views)

Comment: Yeah thanks for clearing that up for me! Managed to get it working with a few tweaks. Thanks for your help

Comment: @BeeNag Would you be willing to post the tweaks you needed to make it work?

Comment: @hlongmore From what I can remember of this, the code I was using has now been changed, I used Dashdrum's answer as a jumping off point but in the end all I ended up doing was using my original view I wrote custom methods for get_queryset, get_context_data and get_form (it was one of the form methods I can't remember which one off the top of my head). I then dropped the form_class from the view. As the data was coming from the same queryset in both instances it was then relatively simple for me to populate both the form with the required data and the table. I hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

An app I'm working on now uses a similar approach.  I start with the ListView, bring in the FormMixin, and then bring in post() from the FormView.

```
class LinkListView(FormMixin, ListView):
    model = Link
    ordering =  ['-created_on']
    paginate_by = 10
    template_name = 'links/link_list.html'

    form_class = OtherUserInputForm

    #=============================================================================#
    #
    #     Handle form input
    #

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Handles POST requests, instantiating a form instance with the passed
        POST variables and then checked for validity.
        """
        form = self.get_form()
        self.form = form
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def put(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.post(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('links')
```

You may also wish to override `get_object()`, `get_queryset()`, and `get_context()`.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm not really sure about the overrides. At the moment the page is rendering with no data, so obviously I need them but I don't really know how they would be used in this context? I have only really used get_context_data() before. Could you possibly elaborate on your suggestion?